# Adding contact to multiple address lists with recipientfilter

Tags: powershell, active-directory, office365, exchange-server

Is there a proper way to add users to multiple address lists, using only a single extensionAttribute on the users?

I'm currently creating some address lists for our employees to use.

Let's say i have an addresslist called "CompanyA" and "CompanyB"
I then have a single user that needs to be shown in both "CompanyA" and "CompanyB".

I have currently created a recipient filter for each addresslist that says

CompanyA:

```
-RecipientFilter "(CustomAttribute14 -like 'CompanyA')"
```

CompanyB:

```
-RecipientFilter "(CustomAttribute14 -like 'CompanyB')"
```

I have then on the user in AD, found extentionAttribute14 and added the values `CompanyA; CompanyB`
In the hopes that the delimiter ; would make it read both values for each list.

I have found this to not work and i think i need to redo the filters on the address lists, but i can't find any sort of hints of where to start or how to approach these filters.

I can of course do

```
-RecipientFilter "(CustomAttribute14 -like 'CompanyB') or (CustomAttribute14 -like 'CompanyA')"
```

However that would take all the users with either values into this list.

Comment: Filter would have to be `-like '*CompanyA*'` since the attribute now contains more than just the single string

Comment: Show us the command you use where you add this `-RecipientFilter`. Depending on the 'flavor' of Exchange, you may want to see if property `CustomAttribute14` really is a [Filterable recipient property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/recipientfilter-properties?view=exchange-ps#filterable-recipient-properties)

Comment: Such a simple thing, yet that fixed it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mathias wrote, i was missing the wildcard tags before and after the name i wanted to filter for.

> Filter would have to be -like '*CompanyA*' since the attribute now
> contains more than just the single string – Mathias R. Jessen